# I'm trying to make a simple header using a one-row table and hr elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

Specifically, what I'm trying to achieve is this (try to imagine it without the table borders):

[image]

where:

- the first column is fixed width and has a `<hr>` element the full column width.
- the second column has the text of the title, and the column width expands to suit.
- the third column has a width that uses all remaining table width and has a `<hr>` element the full column width.

I got this far:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:40px;"><hr></td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;"><strong>Some Title</strong></td>
    <td style="width:90%"><hr></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but this plainly is only "correct" for one table width, and incorrect for all others:
[image]
How can I prevent column 2 from being overwritten by column 3, or force column 3 to only use as much width as it needs?

Comment: "*[But] this plainly is only "correct"...*" - nope, I'd argue it's incorrect in every instance, unless there's a good reason that you're using tables for layout?

Comment: which was the reason for the quotes around the word "correct".  I meant correct in the same way as Spike Milligan when describing the broken town clock in Puckoon: "at least it was correct twice a day". ;-)  But point taken.  The one-row table was a means to an end.

Comment: It's not just that using a table is semantically wrong, it's making the problem harder to solve than it needs to be, Flexbox has the tools to make what you need, while table layout really doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `table-layout: fixed` to `table-layout: auto` and then adding a `min-width: 40px` to your first columns and `width: 100%` to your 3rd columns should do the trick.
Doing so, the last column will fill the available space.

One thing should be noted: Tables are "stiff", so as far as I know it's not possible to give the 3rd column a different width for each row.

See the below example, where the 2nd column "pulls" away the 3rd column to fit the longest row:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="table-layout: auto; width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:40px;min-width: 40px;"><hr></td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;"><strong>Some Title</strong></td>
    <td style="width:100%"><hr></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:40px;min-width: 40px;"><hr></td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;"><strong>Someas longer title</strong></td>
    <td style="width:100%"><hr></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:40px;min-width: 40px"><hr></td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;"><strong>Some very long title to show off</strong></td>
    <td style="width:100%"><hr></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Works a treat.  As my application only ever uses a table of one row the stiffness issue doesn't affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width: max-content;` to the second column:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="table-layout: auto; width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:40px;min-width:40px;"><hr></td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; width: max-content;"><strong>Some Title</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 100%;"><hr></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you just want to create this effekt *"header with line in background"* variants like this one might be an alternative for responsive designs:

```css
.MyH1 {
  position: relative;
 }
.MyH1 h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 6rem;
  background-color: white;
}
.MyH1 hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.2em;    /* has to fit to the padding + font-size of <h1> */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyH1">
    <hr>
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That causes the third column to be fixed, and it eats into the second column width as the container width is reduced.  The behaviour of your HTML seems the same with and without the width directive in column 2.

Comment: OK, I see, my code hasn't been cross-checked against chrome. With Firefox it was fine. After correction it turned out to be almost the same code as that of Alex Berger.... I do not delete the answer because of the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a table for this purpose is really inadequate semantically. Instead, you can use a flex container with three children and the following settings which will also solve your width problems:

```css
.header1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header1>span {
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.header1>span:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
}

.header1>h1 {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.header1>span:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header1">
  <span></span>
  <h1>Some Title</h1>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

If you want the horizontal lines higher, add `position: relative` and a `bottom` value to the spans:

```css
.header1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header1>span {
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
}

.header1>span:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
}

.header1>h1 {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.header1>span:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header1">
  <span></span>
  <h1>Some Title</h1>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using a `<table>` element for data that is not tabular (if you *are* showing tabular data in the `<table>`, and this is a heading for that `<table>`, then use the `<caption>` element to contain that heading).

So, instead of that table approach, I'd suggest the following, using a semantic `<header>` element along with CSS flex layout:

```css
/* using the <header> element to contain the
   custom CSS properties for the 'line': */
header {
  --line-color: #aab;
  --line-size: 0.1rem;
  /* specifying flex-layout on the children: */
  display: flex;
  /* aligning those children to the start of
     the inline-axis (the horizontal axis in
     English, and the axis upon which inline
     elements are laid out): */
  justify-content: start;
}

/* using the pseudo-elements, ::before and
   ::after, to contain the horizontal line: */
header::before,
header::after {
  background-image:
  /* a linear gradient on a vertical axis, going
     downwards (180deg): */
    linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      /* the first color is transparent, and continues
         until the 50% point, minus half of the line-size,
         so the line is centered at 50% on the vertical
         axis: */
      transparent calc(50% - var(--line-size)/2),
      /* we then switch to the --line-color custom property,
         which starts 50% - minus half the line-size and
         continues until a point at 50% plus half the line-size: */
      var(--line-color) calc(50% - var(--line-size)/2) calc(50% + var(--line-size)/2),
      /* and then switching back to transparent: */
      transparent calc(50% + var(--line-size)/2));
  content: '';
}

header::before {
  /* this gives the 'inset' size of the <h1> element,
     adjust to your preference: */
  flex-basis: 4rem;
}

header::after {
  /* this causes the ::after element to expand to take
     up all available space on the line: */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

h1 {
  padding-inline: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title content</h1>
</header>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/0qgrdxho/).